# How to test Ruby code with I18n translations in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, internationalization, rails-i18n

When testing Ruby code with I18n translations in RSpec, I get errors like this:

```
translation missing: en.lib.filter.equal_to
```

Here's a simplified example:

```
def word_for_operator
  I18n.t('lib.filter.equal_to')
end
```

Spec:

```
it "returns the correct label" do
  expect(filter.word_for_operator).to eq("some value")
end
```

Everything works fine in Rails.

How can I use I18n in my specs?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your problem. Are you saying that you have a valid `:en` locale, but RSpec is not using it?

Comment: @Stefan yes that's correct. It works when using the rails app as a gem, or running it standalone, but not in the spec.

Comment: You have to clone your locale.yml to your rails-engine if you run tests from it.

Answer (score -1):

Would not the following solve your ugly-looking-problem? I understand, that’s not a solution you were looking for, but it could be sufficient enough.

```
it "returns the correct humanised label" do
    {
      'lib.quattro_filter.none' => 'None',
      'lib.quattro_filter.and' => 'and',
      ...
    }.each do |name, value|
      allow(I18n).to receive(:t).with(name).and_return(value)
    end
    # the same with expects
end
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, this doesn't solve my problem of needing to do this in every test. There will be quite a few.